# PHP json_decode + Print Array Values Fails

Tags: php, json

```
 stdClass Object ( [free] => 100% δωρεάν [meetsingles] => Γνωρίστε Singles [searchprofiles] => Προφίλ Αναζήτηση )
```

I have a JSON array that after decoded 'json_decode' and printed to screen it looks like above - using UTF8 for Greek.

This is how I print it:

```
$siteLanguages = json_decode($result);
print_r($siteLanguages);
```

When I try to access one of the values the page displays only until the point of the print and then it stops loading - eg: like half a page will show - comment this out and the whole page shows - below is how I'm trying:

```
 print $siteLanguages['searchprofiles'];
```

I can't see why I can't use the associate array like any other.

Is there a trick I'm missing here?
Should the decoded json array show 'stdClass Object' when printed?

thx

Comment: json_decode returns an object, not an array. So you should try something like $siteLanguages->searchprofiles;

Comment: If you'd like to have json_decode return an array, pass `true` as it's second parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're dealing with an object, not array

```
print $siteLanguages -> searchprofiles;
```

Answer (score 1):

The right way is this:
$siteLanguages = json_decode($result,true);
will get an array,your way get an object;